# Need help with simple rewrite rule (shouldn't this be easy?)

Tags: url-rewriting, buddypress, mod-rewrite, domain-mapping

All I need is a rewrite that will change `example.com/anyphrase` into `example.com`.

Here is what I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !wp-admin
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !activity
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !members
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !groups
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php [L]
```

Notes:
I added the above to the top of my `.htaccess` file (in WP root). I am running WordPress 3.1.3 multisite (subdomains), WP MU Domain Mapping plugin, and buddypress on `example.com`. The mapped domain name is `example.com`, not the actual subdomain.

I was assuming that my rewrite rule would load `example.com/index.php`, which would load the homepage for the WordPress site.  However, I get a "page not found" response shown in my buddypress skin (not a full-blown error 404 page).

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is a problem for you still or not, but if so I noticed a few issues. First off, your domain wasn't set to be case-insensitive [NC]. Second, your RewriteRule regex has a character class ending with a dash. This needs to start with a dash. Third, your rule sends the request to index.php, which means index.php needs to know how to handle the request. If you want to redirect, that's different. Give this a whirl and let me know how you make out:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainXYZ\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !activity
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !members
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !groups
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://domainXYZ\.com [L,R=301]
```

Cheers~

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I always appreciate input from folks are good with regex and rewrite rules. Not my strongest suit.

However, I ended up writing the redirection into a WP template hook instead of using a rewrite rule. 

    add_action('template_redirect', 'my_function');